# Proving that if $f'(x)$ exists then $f(x)$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

On an interval $[a,b]$ Assume $f'(x)$ exists. Then prove that $f$ is continuous on the interval.

By the mean value theorem there exists a point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $$f'(x_0)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\\
|f'(x_0)||b-a|=|f(b)-f(a)|$$

Given $\epsilon>0$ choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{|b-a|}$ such that $|f(b)-f(a)|< \epsilon$ whenever $|b-a|<\delta$

My question is :

1) Is this proof correct?

2) If it is correct, then since $\delta$ is always dependent on $f'(x_0)$ or $x_0$ this proof implies that if $f'(x)$ exists $f$ is not uniformly continuous. How come?

Comment: The proof is correct. Now it is not because you found un $\delta$ that depends on $x_0$ that you cannot find one that is independant so you cannot conclude on the uniform continuity for as an example you know that (Heine theorem) if $f$ is continuous on a bounded and closed interval it is uniformly continuous

Comment: The proof is not correct. $a,b$ are the endpoints and are fixed. It doesn't make sense to write $|b-a|<\delta.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a more fundamental proof that does not rely on the MVT. Suppose $f'(x_0)$ exists at some $x_0\in (a,b)$. Then

$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} = f'(x_0)
$$

Since $\lim_{x\to x_0} x - x_0 = 0$, it follows that

$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) - f(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\cdot\lim_{x\to x_0} x - x_0 = f'(x_0)\cdot 0 = 0
$$

Hence $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$, which implies that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. Since $x_0$ was arbitrary in $(a,b)$, $f$ is contiuous on $(a,b)$.